# Docker image created by Bazel does not have repository/tag, files are packed with strange names and do not run

Tags: docker, bazel

I'm trying to pack an application compiled with Bazel into a Docker image, using Bazel.

I have an empty `WORKSPACE` file, the following `main.cc` file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { printf("Hello World\n"); }
```

and the following BUILD file (all in the same folder):

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/docker:docker.bzl", "docker_build")

cc_binary(
  name = "hello",
  srcs = ["main.cc"],
)

docker_build(
  name = "hello_docker",
  files = [":hello"],
  cmd = ["./hello"],
)
```

Gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/yeputons/c90a5d3d6f8b819aadecf68260b1c5bb).

When I run `bazel run :hello`, I can see "Hello World" successfully printed. Then I run `bazel build :hello_docker.tar` which [is supposed](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/docker.html) to generate a full image for docker in `bazel-bin/hello_docker.tar`. Looks like it does.

Then I run:

```
$ docker load -i bazel-bin/hello_docker.tar
51525b594688: Loading layer [==================================================>] 10.24 kB/10.24 kB
Loaded image ID: sha256:252367f43640968343ecd78b2a3533c8ed99c4be66d73fc3ec6ccb137df19625
```

Then I list all images:

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                      TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
ubuntu                          14.04               b969ab9f929b        3 weeks ago         188 MB
docker/whalesay                 latest              6b362a9f73eb        21 months ago       247 MB
<none>                          <none>              252367f43640        292 years ago       8.048 kB
```

Looks like the image which was just loaded does not have any repository or tag associated with it. Why can that be and how do I fix that? The "created" value is huge as expected (Bazel clears timestamps for reproductibility).

When I look inside `hello_docker.tar`, I see something related to the expected repository/tag inside the `repository` file:

```
{
  "bazel/": {
    "hello_docker": "3d529b3ceeb0d9ef33f6225e655f3f5a0e061888f25cd6a3fac11604778ef6a8"
  }
}
```

Another problem: when I try to run the image in a new container, it fails:

```
$ docker run -t -i 25236
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: exec: "./hello": stat ./hello: no such file or directory.
```

I looked inside the generated `tar` file one more time and found out that there is an executable here, but it's named `o` for some reason. Another attempt and a different error:

```
$ docker run -t -i 25236 ./o
write pipe: bad file descriptor
```

Strangely enough, if I pack that `hello` executable with my own `Dockerfile` like this, "Hello World" is printed as expected:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
ADD hello .
CMD ./hello
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix any of these three issues? I think that they're interconnect and I have wrong BUILD file (maybe I should somehow specify which Linux image to use as a base?). Recap:

1. Repository/tag name is not displayed after image generated by Bazel is imported into Docker.
2. `hello` file is added to the image under the name `o`.
3. Even when run as `o`, Dockered executable yields "bad file descriptor" message.

My software versions:

```
$ bazel version
Build label: 0.4.4
Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Wed Feb 1 18:54:21 2017 (1485975261)
Build timestamp: 1485975261
Build timestamp as int: 1485975261

$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Mon, 19 Dec 2016 09:20:48 +1300
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Mon, 19 Dec 2016 09:20:48 +1300
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like the second problem is a [known bug](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1178)

Comment: And symptoms of the third problem are similar to building image with `FROM scratch` instead of `FROM ubuntu:14.04`.

Comment: My current assumption is that Bazel does not allow using any non-Bazel created image as a base, including images from Docker Hub like `ubuntu:14.04`.